# What happens(with respect to memory) when two int variables are given same value in java?

Tags: java

I know that local variables are stored on stack in java. But what happens with respect to memory allocation on stack when two int variables are given same value in java(How are they related)? Is there any kind of copy on write semantic? How does it works then?

Comment: So 4 byte of memory is allocated to each of them because they are different declared variables, SIMPLE as ABC.

Comment: two variables means two slots in memory. The stack is allocated when you enter the method, not on a per line basis.

Comment: We know that == operator compares reference and it's true if same objects are referred. then how does == operator works in case of int if memory slots are different?

Comment: == doesn't compare reference when using primitives, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious answer is that `int x=5; int y=5;` does the same as `int x=5; int y=6;` with the *only* exception being that, in your case, the memory that's been associated with `y` will look the same as as it does for `x`.

It's difficult to envisage a JVM where some kind of *copy on write* semantic is used - i.e. `x` and `y` are allocated the same piece of memory *until* one of them changes the value. As far as I know, that is *theroetically* permissible by the Java Language Specification, but it's unlikely to be used by anything so trivial as an `int`: the overhead in setting up the copy on write would *far* outweigh them having different memory from the outset.

(Out of interest, it was possible to write copy-on-write semantics for the C++ `std::string` class, but since C++11 it's been disallowed).

Comment: We know that == operator compares reference and it's true if same objects are referred.
then how does == operator works in case of int?

Comment: @AyushN: on primitive types, the values are compared.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely create to variable in stack. which hold value 5.
There's no other way.

Any variable local/global,primitive/non-primitive stores some value

For primitive value is some whatever you assign according to type.

For non primitive value is memory address of the object in heap but in the end both holds value and does not lookup if some other var has the same either way.